# resizetoAvoidBottomInset true is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

The onscreen keyboard is hiding my textfield eventhough I have set the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to true .I wrapped the whole body inside a SingleChildScrollView ,still its is not working.

What might be the reason? Below is my code :

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                  children: [
                    
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 16),
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 20,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Color(0xff331070)),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  ),
                  child: TextField(
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      fullname = value;
                    },
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                      labelText: 'Full Name',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
             
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 16),
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 20,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Color(0xff331070)),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  ),
                  child: TextField(
                    inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(100)],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      about = value;
                    },
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      labelText: 'About',
                    ),
                 ) ],),), ], ), ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, your code is totally ok, i've tested it and it's fine. you don't have modal in bottom, all of your widgets are in a scrollable screen. and your textfield won't be hidden. if you're not agree please explain your needs in a better way my friend. many thanks

Comment: Actually I have done this project in an online ide .So in its emulator doesnt show an onscreen keyboard .So I got to know about this issue after I deployed it and run it in my mobile .It is still hiding my textfield like the image above

Comment: you can scroll the page, as you know you have a screen with textformfield, and it is normal, if you had a ModalScreen that was opened  as a stack on your screen you would be afraid of going under keyboard. by the way when you want to fill the textformfield in every pixel of scrollable screen it is normal to scroll the page under keyboard. if you want to test what i mean, please add a Button at the end of screen(by stack not with column) and see that the button comes up the keyboard or will hide behind it? if it comes up the keyboard your code is working fine